# Newrelic error in Django : Configuration has already been done

Tags: python, django, newrelic

I am getting this error when i am trying to run
`python manage.py runserver` for my Django Project,

`newrelic.api.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Configuration has already been done against differing configuration file or environment. Prior configuration file used was "/home/project/newrelic.ini" and environment "staging".'`

What does it mean ?? How to approach it?

Comment: Hey can you please explain how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you just setup New Relic?

I believe this is a problem with your **procfile**. Which you most likely just have edited. 
 
Your procfile should look something like this, depending on your wsgi.

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hello.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: Thanks!,I fixed it, it was due to the absolute path i was giving when i initialise the newrelic ini file